# Write a program, which finds the maximal sequence of consecutive equal elements in an array. c#

Tags: c#

The prompt is to find the maximal sequence of consecutive equal elements in an array. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't get the right result to show up. :/ Maybe the problem is in the way I iterate with the second loop?

```
class Class2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int pos=0, bestpos=0, bestlen = 0;
        int len = 1;
        int[] vargu = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9 };

        for(int i = 0; i < vargu.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if (vargu[i] == vargu[i++])
            {
                len++;
                if (len > bestlen)
                {
                    bestlen = len;
                    bestpos = pos;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                len = 1;
                pos = i++;
            }
        }

        for(int k = bestpos; k <= bestlen; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", vargu[k]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 problems.

1. if (vargu[i] == vargu[i++])
   dont use ++ with i, it means increment the actual value of i, and you are looping i. Use "i+1" instead.
2. pos = i++;

same problem here. the array wont get traversed  by each index due to this line.

1. for(int k = bestpos; k <= bestlen; k++)

k < bestlen + bestpos, because bestpos = 8, and bestlen = 4, so loop run condition fails.

```
int pos = 0, bestpos = 0, bestlen = 0;
            int len = 1;
            int[] vargu = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9 };
            for (int i = 0; i < vargu.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (vargu[i] == vargu[i+1])
                {
                    len++;
                    if (len > bestlen)
                    {
                        bestlen = len;
                        bestpos = pos;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    len = 1;
                    pos = i+1;
                }

            }
             for (int k = bestpos; k < bestlen + bestpos; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", vargu[k]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `i++` in the loop body when you mean `i + 1`.

Note that `i++` has the side effect of *increasing* `i` by 1. Leave the incrementation of `i` solely in `for (int i = 0; i < vargu.Length - 1; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is 2-fold.

First `i++` increments the variable `i` which shifts the index forward. Something that you don't want. You need to use `i+1` if you want to access the consecutive element

Second, when you print in the second loop your array the end-index is wrong. You start at `bestpos` but you want to end at `bestpos + bestlen`! Since you measure the length of the sequence and don't save the final index.

This should give you the expected result:

```
int pos = 0, bestpos = 0, bestlen = 0;
int len = 1;
int[] vargu = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9 };
for (int i = 0; i < vargu.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (vargu[i] == vargu[i+1])
    {
        len++;
        if (len > bestlen)
        {
            bestlen = len;
            bestpos = pos;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        len = 1;
        pos = i+1;
    }
}
for (int k = bestpos; k <= bestpos+bestlen; k++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}", vargu[k]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a structure to hold results :

```
struct ResultItem
{
    public int start;
    public int end;
    public int value;
}
```

And then just iterate and compare when signs are changing :

```
int[] vargu = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9 };
List<ResultItem> _result = new List<ResultItem>();
ResultItem current = new ResultItem{ value = vargu[0], start = 0, end = 1 };
for (int i = 1; i < vargu.Length; i++)
{
     if (vargu [i] != current.value)
     {
         current.end = i;
        _result.Add( current );   
         current = new ResultItem { value = vargu[i], start = i, end = i };
     }
    Console.WriteLine(current.value + "  " + current.start + "   " + current.end);
}
current.end = vargu.Length;
_result.Add(current);
```

Then you can dump the result as such :

```
foreach(ResultItem value in _result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("integer {0} was placed {1} times in a row", value.value, value.end - value.start);
}
```

which should result in something like :

```
integer 2 was placed 2 times in a row
integer 3 was placed 1 times in a row
integer 4 was placed 1 times in a row
integer 5 was placed 3 times in a row
integer 6 was placed 1 times in a row
integer 9 was placed 4 times in a row
```

Then to find the longest sequence you can use Linq : `_result.Max(r => r.end - r.start);`

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same problem myself.  I tried using Mong Zhu's code above and it almost worked so I tweaked two things and it seemed to work.
Change (vargu[i] == vargu[i+1]) to (vargu[i] + 1 == vargu[i+1])
And pos = i + 1; to pos = i; and it seemed to work.  My first post. I hope it's okay.

```
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 0 };
        int pos = 0, bestPos = 0, bestLen = 0;
        int len = 1; 

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length -1; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] + 1 == arr[i + 1])
            {
                len++;
                if(len > bestLen)
                {
                    bestLen = len;
                    bestPos = pos; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                len = 1;
                pos = i ;
            }
        }

        for( int k = bestPos; k <= bestLen + bestPos; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", arr[k]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            int finalbestsum = 0;
            int bestsum = 0;
            
            int bestcount = 0;
            int count = 0;
            
            int consval = 0;
            int? consval1 = null;
            
            string bestvalue = null;
            string bestvalue1 = null;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of columns for the array");

            int col = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows for the array");

            int  row = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[,] twodimen = new int[row, col];

            
            for (int index = 0; index < twodimen.GetLength(0); index++ )
            {
                for (int index1 = 0; index1 < twodimen.GetLength(1); index1++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter twodimen {0} {1} value",index, index1);
                    twodimen[index, index1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());      
                }
            }
            
            for (int index = 0; index < twodimen.GetLength(0);  index++ )
            
            {
                for (int index1 = 0; index1 < twodimen.GetLength(1)-1; index1++)
                {
                    consval = twodimen[index,index1];

                    if (consval == twodimen[index, index1 + 1])
                    {
                        consval1 = twodimen[index,index1+1];
                        //Console.Write("{0}" + " ", consval);

                        bestvalue = bestvalue +  Convert.ToString(" " + consval + " ");
                        count++;
                        bestsum = bestsum + consval;
                    }
                    else if (consval1 != null)                    
                    { 
                        //Console.Write(consval1);
                        count++;
                        bestvalue = bestvalue + Convert.ToString(" " + consval1 + " ");

                        bestsum = bestsum + Convert.ToInt16(consval1);
                       Console.WriteLine();
                       if (bestcount < count)
                        {
                        bestvalue1 = bestvalue;
                        bestcount   = count;
                        finalbestsum = bestsum;
                        }
                       else if (bestcount == count && finalbestsum < bestsum)
                       {
                           bestvalue1 = bestvalue;
                           bestcount = count;
                           finalbestsum = bestsum;
                       }
                        bestvalue = null;
                        count = 0;
                        bestsum = 0;
                        consval1 = null;
                    }
                     
                    if (consval == twodimen[index, index1 + 1] && index1 == (twodimen.GetLength(1)-2))
                    {
                            bestvalue = bestvalue + Convert.ToString(" " + consval1 + " ");
                            //Console.Write(consval1);
                            bestsum = bestsum + Convert.ToInt16(consval1);
                            count++;
                            consval1 = null;
                        
                        if (bestcount < count)
                        {
                            bestcount = count;
                            bestvalue1 = bestvalue;
                            finalbestsum = bestsum;    
                        }
                        else if (bestcount == count && finalbestsum < bestsum)
                        {
                            bestvalue1 = bestvalue;
                            bestcount = count;
                            finalbestsum = bestsum;
                        }
                    }
                }
                bestvalue = null;
                count = 0;
                bestsum = 0;
                Console.WriteLine();
                //Console.WriteLine(bestcount);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(bestvalue1);
            Console.ReadLine();        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to learning C#. I have tried to create a solution to find the Maximum number of time a number has occurred in row in two dimensional array , if two number has occurred same times then the its check for the sum of the highest one and prints it.

Comment: Please put your comment as a description for your code.