# How to find the longest sequence of equal elements in an array of integers?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to write a program that finds the **longest sequence of equal elements** in an array of **integers**. If **several longest sequences exist**, we should print the **leftmost one**. e.g.

```
Input: 0 1 1 5 2 2 6 3 3 

Output: 1 1
```

I know that my code doesn't work correctly, but I don't know how to fix it. I should solve the problem using only arrays because I don't know how to use lists.

```
int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            int[] currentSequenceOfEqualElements = new int[numbers.Length];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                {
                    if (currentSequenceOfEqualElements[0] == 0)
                    {
                        currentSequenceOfEqualElements[0] = numbers[i];
                        currentSequenceOfEqualElements[1] = numbers[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentSequenceOfEqualElements[i + 2] = numbers[i];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', currentSequenceOfEqualElements));
        }
```

I will be very grateful if you can explain to me how to do it.

Comment: I'd suggest having a play with [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)'s `GroupAdjacent` and `MaxBy`.

Comment: check this one ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979383/write-a-program-which-finds-the-maximal-sequence-of-consecutive-equal-elements

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution using the MoreLinq library (https://morelinq.github.io/) that mjwills suggested.
Once you get used to linq and morelinq methods the code is easier to understand than custom algo with nested loops and if.

```
        var numbers = new int[]{ 0, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3};
        var result = numbers.GroupAdjacent(x => x)
                       .MaxBy(x => x.Count())
                       .FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var i in result)
        {
            Console.Write($"{i} ");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution, using only loops and no linq. It should be nice and easy to understand.

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3 };

// Some variables to keep track of the sequence we're currently looking
// at, and the longest sequence we've found so far. We're going to start
// the loop at the 2nd number, so we'll initialize these as if we've
// already processed the first number (which is 0, so we've seen the
// first number of a sequence of 0's).        

// Number of numbers in the current sequence
int count = 1;
// Number which is part of the longest sequence so faar
int longestNum = numbers[0];
// Number of numbers in the longest sequence we've seen so far
int longestCount = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    // We're starting a new sequence
    if (numbers[i] != numbers[i-1])
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    count++;
    // Have we just found a new longest sequence?
    if (count > longestCount)
    {
        longestCount = count;
        longestNum = numbers[i];
    }
}

// longestNum = 1 and longestCount = 2 (because the longest sequence
// had 2 1's in it). Turn this into the string "1 1".
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat(longestNum, longestCount)));

// If you wanted to end up with an array containing [1, 1], then:
int[] result = new int[longestCount];
Array.Fill(result, longestNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will illustrate a recursive answer for your question, below is the code, I kept some if-else statements that there is no need to have them, but at least the code shows the idea.
The code has a basic method that should be exposed as public and a private recursive method that does the heavy lifting. The longest sequence is the empty array(list)

```
 var longSequenceEqualElem = new List<int>();
```

Later on the recursion, you pass all the elems of the array through all the recursion calls to keep querying the positions, the pos parameter indicates the position level of the recursion.

if (pos < elems.Length) //stop the recursion here, the position will fall out of the indexes of the array, just return what you have in `sequence` that should be the longest.

The following statement `if (sequence.Contains(elems[pos]))` means that you found the same number you were carrying on the sequence in the position pos, so you can add it to the sequence and call the recursion with the adjacent position(pos + 1)
If the element in position pos is not part of the sequence you had, then you need to call the recursion with a new sequence containing elems[pos] and later compare the result of that recursion call with the sequence you had to see which of them is the longest one.
Hope this helps

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var elemts = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3 };

            var result = LongestSequence(elemts);

            foreach (var i in result)
            {
                Console.Write(i + "\t");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int[] LongestSequence(int[] elems)
        {
            var longSequenceEqualElem = new List<int>();
            return LongestSequenceRec(elems, longSequenceEqualElem, 0);
        }

        private static int[] LongestSequenceRec(int[] elems, List<int> sequence, int pos)
        {
            if (pos < elems.Length)
            {
                if (sequence.Contains(elems[pos]))
                {
                    sequence.Add(elems[pos]);
                    return LongestSequenceRec(elems, sequence, pos + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    var newSeq = LongestSequenceRec(elems, new List<int> { elems[pos] }, pos + 1);
                    return (newSeq.Length > sequence.Count) ? newSeq.ToArray() : sequence.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return sequence.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] array1 = new int[9] {0, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3};
        int[] array2 = new int[9] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        int max_count = 1;
        int tempCount = 1;
        int num = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (array1[i] == array1[i + 1]) tempCount++;
            else tempCount = 1;

            if (tempCount > max_count)
            {
                max_count = tempCount;
                num = array1[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++) array2[i] = num;

        for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)  Console.Write(array2[i] + " ");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```